# Why does the logistic curve not grow the fastest when $y = \frac{L}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the y-value where a logistic model grows the fastest is the limit to infinity divided by 2.

$y = \frac{L}{2}, L = \lim_{t\to\infty} y$

However, this doesn't always seem to be the case. Sometimes, I am told that the point where the curve is the steepest is $\frac{L}{2}$, but sometimes, I am told that I need to find the points of inflection of the curve.

This problem is an example where the answer doesn't seem to fit the $\frac{L}{2}$ definition. The growth of a population is modeled by the logistic differential equation:

$\frac{dP}{dt} = 2P \left( 1-\frac{P}{5} \right)$

At what point $P$ does the population grow the fastest?

Since the model fits the template $\frac{dP}{dt} = kP \left( 1-\frac{P}{L} \right)$, finding the value of $L$ is straightforward: 5. The answer is $10$ and not $\frac{5}{2}$ for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: I think the quantity $2y (1 - \frac{y}{5})$ becomes maximal for $y = 2.5 = \frac{5}{2}$. How did you arrive at the answer $y = 10$?

Comment: I arrived at the same answer you did. My textbook says that y = 10 is the answer, but I don't understand why that is the case.

Comment: Textbooks do occasionally have errors in their "back-of-the-book" answers (a well-edited book may still have one in 300 to 500 answers incorrect, in my experience).  I suspect either someone solved $ \ 4P/5 \ = \ 2 \ $ incorrectly "in their head" or the problem was revised at some point without altering the answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with your differential equation. You wrote $\displaystyle\frac{dP}{dt}$ on the LHS, then changed your variable to $y$ on the RHS. Here is your hint: The population grows the fastest when $\displaystyle\frac{dP}{dt}$ is maximized, so its derivative is equal to zero. What is the derivative of $\displaystyle\frac{dP}{dt}$? 
Next, your value 10 does not make sense because it is above the carrying capacity $L =5$ for the population. If you want the point to be on the logistic curve, then it must be less than $L$. When $0 < P < L$, the rate of change of the population is maximized when $P = \displaystyle\frac{L}{2}$. To find the point of the rate of maximal change, set the derivative of the RHS (with respect to $y$) equal to zero, then solve.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the "y" typo. When I differentiate, I get the zeros 0, 5 and 10 for P. My textbook says that y = 10 is the point of maximum change, but I cannot make sense of this answer.

Comment: The values 0 and 5 are equilibrium solutions to the differential equation, since they force the RHS to equal zero. Define $f(P) = 2P(1 - P/5)$. Then $f'(P) = 2 - 4P/5$. This is equal to zero when $P = 5/2$. This is the value of maximal change, since then the second derivative of P is equal to zero.